# React modal won't execute GraphQL query

Tags: reactjs, database, graphql

I was given a task to update and improve the UI of an existing React app without prior knowledge to GraphQL, so it's my first time. It's a simple app where you can edit and delete items. My task is to style and add a react-modal functionality for the **Edit** and **Update** forms. After adding the features the modal works as well as the changehandler for each form but the edit and delete features doesn't work anymore. Need help.

Here's the old code for the List item without react-modal:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { EXECUTE } from '@nostack/no-stack';
import compose from '@shopify/react-compose';
import { graphql } from '@apollo/react-hoc';

import {
  UPDATE_ITEM_FOR_LIST_ACTION_ID,
  DELETE_ITEM_FOR_LIST_ACTION_ID,
} from '../../../config';

import EditInstanceForm from '../../EditInstanceForm';
import DeleteInstanceMenu from '../../DeleteInstanceMenu';
import ItemStyleWrapper from '../../Items';
import Button from '../../Items';

function Item({
  item,
  parentId,
  selected,
  updateInstance,
  deleteInstance,
  refetchQueries,
  onSelect,
}) {
  const [itemValue, updateItemValue] = useState(item.value);
  const [isEditMode, updateIsEditMode] = useState(false);
  const [isSaving, updateIsSaving] = useState(false);
  const [isDeleteMode, updateIsDeleteMode] = useState(false);
  const [isDeleting, updateIsDeleting] = useState(false);

  if (!selected) {
    return (
      <ItemStyleWrapper onClick={() => onSelect(item.id)}>
        {itemValue}
      </ItemStyleWrapper>
    );
  }

  function handleItemValueChange(e) {
    updateItemValue(e.target.value);
  }

  async function handleItemValueSave() {
    updateIsSaving(true);

    await updateInstance({
      variables: {
        actionId: UPDATE_ITEM_FOR_LIST_ACTION_ID,
        executionParameters: JSON.stringify({
          value: itemValue,
          instanceId: item.id,
        }),
      },
      refetchQueries,
    });

    updateIsEditMode(false);
    updateIsSaving(false);
    console.log('Saving');
  }

  function handleCancelEdit() {
    updateIsEditMode(false);
  }

  if (isEditMode) {
    return (
      <ItemStyleWrapper>
        <EditInstanceForm
          id={item.id}
          label='Item Value:'
          value={itemValue}
          onChange={handleItemValueChange}
          onSave={handleItemValueSave}
          onCancel={handleCancelEdit}
          disabled={isSaving}
        />
      </ItemStyleWrapper>
    );
  }

  async function handleDelete() {
    updateIsDeleting(true);

    try {
      await deleteInstance({
        variables: {
          actionId: DELETE_ITEM_FOR_LIST_ACTION_ID,
          executionParameters: JSON.stringify({
            parentInstanceId: parentId,
            instanceId: item.id,
          }),
        },
        refetchQueries,
      });
    } catch (e) {
      updateIsDeleting(false);
    }
    console.log('Deleting');
  }

  function handleCancelDelete() {
    updateIsDeleteMode(false);
  }

  if (isDeleteMode) {
    return (
      <ItemStyleWrapper selected={selected} isDeleting={isDeleting}>
        {itemValue}
        <DeleteInstanceMenu
          onDelete={handleDelete}
          onCancel={handleCancelDelete}
          disabled={isDeleting}
        />
      </ItemStyleWrapper>
    );
  }

  return (
    <ItemStyleWrapper selected={selected}>
      {itemValue}
      <Button type='button' onClick={() => updateIsEditMode(true)}>
        &#9998;
      </Button>
      <Button type='button' onClick={() => updateIsDeleteMode(true)}>
        &#128465;
      </Button>
    </ItemStyleWrapper>
  );
}

export default compose(
  graphql(EXECUTE, { name: 'updateInstance' }),
  graphql(EXECUTE, { name: 'deleteInstance' })
)(Item);
```

Here's the new and updated code of the same component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { EXECUTE } from '@nostack/no-stack';
import compose from '@shopify/react-compose';
import { graphql } from '@apollo/react-hoc';

import ModalContainer from '../../Modals/ModalContainer';
import '../../Modals/modals.css';
import { FaCheck, FaTrashAlt, FaEdit } from 'react-icons/fa';

import {
  UPDATE_ITEM_FOR_LIST_ACTION_ID,
  DELETE_ITEM_FOR_LIST_ACTION_ID,
} from '../../../config';

import EditInstanceForm from '../../EditInstanceForm';
import DeleteInstanceMenu from '../../DeleteInstanceMenu';
import ItemStyleWrapper from '../../Items';
import Button from '../../Items';
import ItemCheckBox from '../../Items';
import ItemValueContainer from '../../Items';

function Item({
  item,
  parentId,
  selected,
  updateInstance,
  deleteInstance,
  refetchQueries,
  onSelect,
}) {
  const [itemValue, updateItemValue] = useState(item.value);
  const [editModal, setEditModal] = useState(false);
  const [isSaving, updateIsSaving] = useState(false);
  const [deleteModal, setDeleteModal] = useState(false);
  const [isDeleting, updateIsDeleting] = useState(false);
  const [isChecked, updateIsChecked] = useState(false);

  const handleEditModal = () => setEditModal((prevState) => !prevState);
  const handleDeleteModal = () => setDeleteModal((prevState) => !prevState);

  if (!selected) {
    return (
      <ItemStyleWrapper>
        <ItemCheckBox htmlFor={item.id}>
          <input
            type='checkbox'
            id={item.id}
            checked={isChecked}
            onChange={handleItemCheckedStatus}
          />
          <FaCheck />
        </ItemCheckBox>
        <ItemValueContainer
          onClick={() => onSelect(item.id)}
          isChecked={isChecked}
        >
          {itemValue}
        </ItemValueContainer>
      </ItemStyleWrapper>
    );
  }

  function handleItemCheckedStatus() {
    updateIsChecked((previousState) => !previousState);
  }

  function handleItemValueChange(e) {
    updateItemValue(e.target.value);
    console.log(itemValue);
  }

  async function handleItemValueSave() {
    updateIsSaving(true);

    await updateInstance({
      variables: {
        actionId: UPDATE_ITEM_FOR_LIST_ACTION_ID,
        executionParameters: JSON.stringify({
          value: itemValue,
          instanceId: item.id,
        }),
      },
      refetchQueries,
    });

    updateIsSaving(false);
    await handleEditModal();
    console.log('Saving');
  }

  function handleCancelEdit() {
    handleEditModal();
  }

  async function handleDelete() {
    updateIsDeleting(true);
    try {
      await deleteInstance({
        variables: {
          actionId: DELETE_ITEM_FOR_LIST_ACTION_ID,
          executionParameters: JSON.stringify({
            parentInstanceId: parentId,
            instanceId: item.id,
          }),
        },
        refetchQueries,
      });
      await handleDeleteModal();
    } catch (e) {
      updateIsDeleting(false);
    }
    console.log('Deleting');
  }

  function handleCancelDelete() {
    handleDeleteModal();
  }

  return (
    <ItemStyleWrapper selected={selected}>
      <ItemCheckBox htmlFor={item.id}>
        <input
          type='checkbox'
          id={item.id}
          checked={isChecked}
          onChange={handleItemCheckedStatus}
        />
      </ItemCheckBox>
      <ItemValueContainer>{itemValue}</ItemValueContainer>

      <Button type='button' onClick={handleEditModal}>
        <FaEdit />
      </Button>
      <Button type='button' onClick={handleDeleteModal}>
        <FaTrashAlt />
      </Button>

      <ModalContainer status={editModal} exitHandler={handleEditModal}>
        <div className='modal-body'>
          <EditInstanceForm
            id={item.id}
            label='Item Value:'
            value={itemValue}
            onChange={handleItemValueChange}
            onSave={handleItemValueSave}
            onCancel={handleCancelEdit}
            disabled={isSaving}
          />
        </div>
      </ModalContainer>

      <ModalContainer status={deleteModal} exitHandler={handleDeleteModal}>
        <div className='modal-body'>
          <ItemValueContainer>{itemValue}</ItemValueContainer>
          <DeleteInstanceMenu
            onDelete={handleDelete}
            onCancel={handleCancelDelete}
            disabled={isDeleting}
          />
        </div>
      </ModalContainer>
    </ItemStyleWrapper>
  );
}

export default compose(
  graphql(EXECUTE, { name: 'updateInstance' }),
  graphql(EXECUTE, { name: 'deleteInstance' })
)(Item);
```

And here's the react-modal code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import './modals.css';

const ModalContainer = ({ children, status, exithandler }) => {
  return (
    <Modal isOpen={status} onRequestClose={exithandler}>
      {children}
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default ModalContainer;
```

Comment: Any logs or errors? Network response code?

Comment: @bravemaster No network errors except the console.log('Saving'); and console.log('Deleting'); of the save and delete handler of the forms doesn't show up on the modal version.